# Cannot install NPM on Vagrant during provision

Tags: node.js, npm, vagrant, provisioning

During Vagrant Shell provision I try to install NodeJS and NPM on Debian Wheezy.
Script is (from guide https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/backports.debian.org):

```
sudo echo "deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian wheezy-backports main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs-legacy
curl https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh
```

Node sets up as a charm, but NPM installation fails:

Stderr from the command:

```
stdin: is not a tty
dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: No such file or directory
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  7810  100  7810    0     0   1407      0  0:00:05  0:00:05 --:--:-- 18956
fetching: http://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-1.3.15.tgz
npm-install-2877.sh: 270: npm-install-2877.sh: cannot open /dev/tty: No such device or address
Aborted 0.x cleanup.  Exiting.
It failed
```

I've googled about two days - can't find any solution :(

## UPD

If to set a Vagrant config like this:

```
config.ssh.shell = "bash -c 'BASH_ENV=/etc/profile exec bash'"
```

Then script doesn't say anything about tty, but still fails:

```
Stderr from the command:

dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: No such file or directory
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  7810  100  7810    0     0   1412      0  0:00:05  0:00:05 --:--:-- 19772
fetching: http://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-1.3.15.tgz
npm-install-3013.sh: 270: npm-install-3013.sh: cannot open /dev/tty: No such device or address
Aborted 0.x cleanup.  Exiting.
It failed
```

Answer (score 14):

The install script tries to access `/dev/tty` to ask if it should clean old versions, which apparently doesnt work with gui-less vagrant boxes. You can set this behaviour using the environment variable `clean`, too, so it doesnt have to ask:

Change the curl statement to this: `curl https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo clean=no sh`.

You can use `clean=yes`, too, if you prefer.

Comment: thanx a lot, but this trick didn't work :(
log says ```mknod: `/dev/tty': File exists``` before curl and the same error after

Comment: take a look at post UPD please

Answer (score 11):

In case anyone, get the following error after trying **curl https://npmjs.org/install.sh**

```
sh: 1: cannot open html: No such file
sh: 2: Syntax error: redirection unexpected
```

Try to do the following instead:

```
curl https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh
```

Apparently, the npm domain needs to use www prefix.

Comment: true, but this is nothing to do with the question asked

Comment: it's not related to this question in any way

Comment: this answer, although not related to the question, helped me. When I googled for "npm cannot open html: No such file" I came here, so... :P